# Is there a term that denotes 'molecules and molecular constituents'?

Tags: terminology

In my notes, I've used phrases such as 'atom, particle, or molecule' more often than I'd like. For example, Wikipedia defines atomic mass as

> the mass of an atomic particle, sub-atomic particle, or molecule.

I remember concise definitions more easily, so a single word for 'molecules and molecular constituents' would be useful.

Is there such a term?

Comment: As a general rule for these definitions, have a the *Coloured Books* of the **IUPAC** (International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry)! In this case, you can find the definitions for [molecule](http://goldbook.iupac.org/M04002.html) and [molecular entity](http://goldbook.iupac.org/M03986.html) in the **IUPAC Compendium of Chemical Terminology**, known as the **Gold Book**.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha That's a good answer. Care to put it as an answer? I'd accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is pretty much link-only, but anyway...*

When searching for *official* definitions, nomenclature, or recommended procedures, the organisation providing all these is the **IUPAC** (International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry)!

An IUPAC book series, known as the **Colour Books**, provides the normative definitions and guidelines on various topics. These are the results of what chemists in the different committees in the IUPAC divisions have eventually agreed upon.

To my knowledge, all these **Colour Books** are available online.

---

As kindly mentioned by *Loong* in a comment, the online versions are not necessary the latest ones! The online version of the [IUPAC Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/) is from 1993. In addition, a [2004 draft copy](http://old.iupac.org/reports/provisional/abstract04/BB-prs310305/CompleteDraft.pdf) is legally available.

---

Organic chemists will often refer to the **Blue Book** (Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry), inorganic chemists to the **Red Book** (Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry), etc.

As far as your question is concerned, the **Gold Book** (IUPAC Compendium of Chemical Terminology) provides the definitions for [molecule](http://goldbook.iupac.org/M04002.html) and [molecular entity](http://goldbook.iupac.org/M03986.html).

Comment: This is far more than a 'link only' answer - great explanations of the IUPAC online resources

Comment: Unfortunately, the current version of the Blue Book (2013) is not legally available online yet. You can only find the old recommendations (1979 and 1993).

Comment: @Loong Yeah they still want you to buy the hardcover book or the online access. Not a very nice thing, since it is very expensive and most organic chemists/ research centers should have access to it.